# Call Oracle Stored Procedure with cursor out parameter

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm developing a web project using zend framework 2.3.7 with oracle database and zend_db (with pdo_oci driver). I have a stored procedure with output parameter which is a cursor that refers to 'select name from customers'. I've tried using the library set of Zend_Db_Statement_Oracle, ParamaterContainer but I couldn't achieve it.

How can I get this to work?